# Do you know any Web Search apps where you can specify more engines/websites at a time?

Tags: search, webapp-rec, website, search-engine

**Google** is the **Web Search** engine that I use more often, but I would like to know if there are web apps where you can define a list of search engines or website you want to retrieve the data for, in a single shot.

The idea is to specify, for example, that I want retrieve the **search results** from:

- 10 top results from **Google**
- 10 from **Bing**
- 10 from **Microsoft MSDN Forums**
- 10 from **Stack Overflow**

Do you know something useful?

Comment: **Search3** [Try it here](http://www.search3.com/)

Comment: back in the old days this would be called "meta-search"

Comment: [Ixquick.com](http://www.ixquick.com)

Comment: I would really like to add also search of some specific website, this would help during search of specific topic like programming issues, etc.

Comment: you know about the "site:" syntax in Google, don't you?

Comment: @CrhisF thank you, but most of times is not the same thing as using the internal search, sometimes could be better, sometimes worst

Answer (score 2):

[MetCrawler](http://www.metacrawler.com) is an online solution:

> MetaCrawler.com utilizes metasearch technology to compile results from many of the Web's major search properties, delivering more relevant and comprehensive results every time you search. By accessing multiple search engines for each query, MetaCrawler.com provides you with a richer and more relevant spectrum of results than you would from using any single search engine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that's been around for a while:

http://www.dogpile.com/

From the front page, it looks like it searches Google, Yahoo, Bing and Ask.

> Powered by [Metasearch](http://www.dogpile.com/dogpile/ws/metasearch/rfcid=1384/rfcp=main/_iceUrlFlag=11?_IceUrl=true) technology, Dogpile returns all the best results from leading search engines including Google, Yahoo!, Bing and Ask, so you find what you’re looking for faster.

[Source](http://www.dogpile.com/dogpile/ws/about/_iceUrlFlag=11?_IceUrl=true)